# I can't find Github in android studio VCS checkout from version control

Tags: android, github

In android studio in checkout from version control I used to have GitHub as an option now its gone and I only have Git present.
I have the plugin checked and I have logged in to GitHub and tested the connection from android studio with success.
What can I do?

[This is the checkout from version control image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enRO4.png)

[This is the plugin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2N0K.png)

Answer (score 1):

use the Git option. You can clone a repository from github by checking out from git

Comment: okay thank you i will try it out, but do you have any idea why GitHub is not available?

Comment: If you say you have seen it before they must have removed it in the update.